# Search Set Of Key Value Pairs in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a list of all possible unique product variant combinations in a JSON object [This is how woocommerce is building it]. Say for example I have a product which comes in 2 sizes - size1 and size2 and colors - color1 and color2:

```
variant_list = [
       {
          "variation_id":328,
          "attributes":{
             "size":"size1",
             "color":"color1"
          }
       },
       {
          "variation_id":329,
          "attributes":{
             "size":"size2",
             "color":"color1"
          }
       },
       {
          "variation_id":330,
          "attributes":{
             "size":"size1",
             "color":"color2"
          }
       },
       {
          "variation_id":331,
          "attributes":{
             "size":"size2",
             "color":"color2"
          }
       ]
```

If user has selected a particular size and color combination (using radio buttons), say for example, size2 and color1 has been chosen, I need to pass the variation id: 329 to my back-end. What is the best way to search my JSON with the attributes criteria set = {"size":"size2","color":"color1"}.

My variant_list object is given - I cannot change it, but my criteria object CAN be built as needed to make this search simple and efficient.

What I have tried and works too, but I know is old school and inefficient :-(
http://jsfiddle.net/v18h6qta/6/

Comment: Hold on. My JSFiddle got reverted to old version. I will fix it now.

Comment: Hi  @user1880957   check my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/) library functions [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find),[findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) or any other that suites you to find the field.

For example

you can use something thing like (I am using javascript)

```
result = _U.findWhere(variant_list,{size:'user value',color:'user value'});
console.log(result.variation_id);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: underscore.js seems to be the right bet. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple updated in your fiddle 
i have added this code

```
function find(){
    var a=$("input[name=size]:checked").val();
    var b=$("input[name=color]:checked").val();

     for(var i=0;i< variant_list.length; i++){
         if(variant_list[i].attributes.size==a &&variant_list[i].attributes.color==b ){
           alert(variant_list[i].variation_id);   
         }
    }  

}
```

[Click the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v18h6qta/12/)